# What are the options for a thin light source (e.g. LED)?

Tags: arduino, electronics

I'm looking to make or buy something resembling an LED, that would be thin (about 0.5mm or less) and cheap (<0.1$ in mass production).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Michael, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with an actual LED? Size 0402 is about your size spec.
[This one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SML-P11MTT86/511-1652-2-ND/2036457) is $0.06 at 10k quantity.

Comment: Nothing wrong, it looks great. I'd like to have a few more directions though. +1